# AJAX bring the complete file instead data - VB.NET

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-ajax

hope you can help me with this issue. I'm trying to get a list from the server side to javascript, using AJAX and VB.NET. I tried several things but it always ***return the complete file instead the list.***

I tried with Javascript and Jquery AJAX, but always had the same result.
In resume:
Connection on DAL.vb file  -> Calling the DAL on Presenter.vb -> Returns to ASCX.VB file code behind.

```
**My Presenter:**
      Public Function GetMenuFromDB() As String
            ....authorization code
                    valueToSet = _accDAL.GetMenuDetailsByUser(UserID) -> my connection to DB
                End If
                If valueToSet.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim serializer As New JsonSerializerOptions()
                    Dim json As String = Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(valueToSet)
                    Return json
                End If
      End Function

**My file ascx.vb:**
<WebMethod()>
        Protected Shared Function GetMenuFromDB(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) As String
            Dim presenter As New MenuPresenter()
            Return presenter.GetMenuFromDB() 
        End Function]

**My JS:**
function getMenuByUser() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "~/Menu.ascx/GetMenuFromDB"
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

OR Jquery:
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "~/Menu.ascx/GetMenuFromDB",
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

But I put a breakpoint on the ascx.vb and never enters.
I change the URL for differents types but doesn't works.
Also I try to move the method to point the aspx file instead ascx, just in case, but it worked with the same result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues.

The whole page is being returned, and this tends to occur when the ajax call is messed up or not even valid (so the whole web page is simply refreshed and return to the client side. So, this occurs when you don't have valid JavaScript code.

A few more things:

Path names used in JavaScript are NOT the same syntax and format as client side (JavaScript) code.

So, for example, you using "~/". Unfortunately, that is a not valid in client side code.

And in nearly all cases, the path name you want to use needs to be the current page, or relative to the current page.

So, if your current page is say inside of a test folder, then you have to go (say) down one folder to the root.

So, if our current page is say in a folder called Testing, then we would have to use this:

```
 url: "../Menu.ascx/GetMenuFromDB"
```

So the "~/" is ONLY for server side code (code behind) that gets processed by asp.net and your code.

In fact, the above same issue exists for say a asp:Image control versus a non one!

You can't for example use:

```
       <img src="~/Content/Pictures/dog.png">
```

However, if you using a asp.net control then above is valid.

In most cases, this is not much of a issue, but it often can become a issue, and that is especially when using a master page.

Since your master page path is usually root, but any old page nested a few folders down in any folder can STILL OFTEN use the master page? Then your path names can get messed up.

So, for example, I wanted in all pages a JavaScript toast message routine.

So, in my master page, I have this:

```
    <%: Scripts.Render("/Scripts/jquery.toast.min.js") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.toast.min.css") %>
```

Note how I did not just drop in a script tag reference for the above. (since I did not want a messed up path name).

Now, let's deal with your ajax example.

First up, in most cases, you don't need to serialize the class, since that is the default and is automatic done by the server.

And in many cases, if the web method is only going to be used/called in a given page, then I drop the web method into that given page, since then while viewing the page markup, I can easy flip to code behind, and I don't have to go hunting around for some ascx page that contains the web method.

And the bonus is then in general I don't have to worry about path name issues in JavaScript, since it on the same page, and thus no path name is required anyway!

So, let's do a example on a test page, and thus not use ascx.

So, keeping above in mind:

We can't and don't use "~/" in JavaScript - no such syntax is allowed.

Any web method is automatic serialized for you - no need to use JavaScript or NewtonSoft serializer here.

And one whopper that always seems to bite me time, and always forget: check the route.config routine in RouteConfig.vb. You will see/find this:

```
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
```

Change above to this:

```
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off
```

LAST tip:

Data returned to a web method call is returned as MyResult.d

Note the .d

Your return data is returned in the ".d". This is just a .net thing.

So, let's setup a simple page, put some controls on the page. So, when we select a dropdown list, we will do this 100% client side, without a post-back, and without a round trip.

So, for server vs client side addressing, here is the page markup:

```
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <link  href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="padding:35px">


            <h4>Select fighter</h4>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboFigher" runat="server" Width="300"
                DataTextField="Fighter"
                DataValueField="ID"
                onchange="mychange(this)"
                >
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <br />


        <div class="mybox" style="float:left;border:solid 1px">
            <div style="text-align: center; padding: 2px 10px 12px 10px">
                <h3 id="Fighter" runat="server"></h3>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
                    Width="180" Height="120" />
                <h4>Engine</h4>
                <asp:Label ID="EngineLabel" runat="server" Text="" />
                <h4>Description</h4>
                <asp:Label ID="DescLabel" runat="server" width="400px"
                    Text="" style="text-align:left" Font-Size="Large" />
            </div>
        </div>

            <script>

                function mychange(myitem) {
                    // get record from server, update
                    // dom values
                    var iPK = myitem.value
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "FighterOneAJ.aspx/GetFighter",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ PK : iPK}),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (rData) {
                            var F = rData.d
                            $('#Image2').attr("src", F.ImagePath)
                            $('#Fighter').text(F.Fighter)
                            $('#EngineLabel').text(F.Engine)
                            $('#DescLabel').text(F.Description)

                        },
                        failure: function (rData) {
                            alert("error " + rData.d);
                        }
                    });

                }

            </script>



        </div>
    </form>
```

And now the code behind for this page:

I am including the full page code behind:

```
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class FighterOneAJ
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then

            cboFigher.DataSource =
                MyRst("SELECT ID, Fighter FROM Fighters ORDER BY Fighter")
            cboFigher.DataBind()
            cboFigher.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Fighter", "0"))

        End If

    End Sub


    <WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function GetFighter(PK As String) As clsFigher

        Dim OneFigher As New clsFigher

        OneFigher.ID = PK
        Return OneFigher


    End Function


    Public Class clsFigher
        Public Fighter As String
        Public Engine As String
        Public Thrust As String
        Public Description As String
        Public ImagePath As String
        Private m_id As Integer

        Public Property ID As Integer
            Get
                Return m_id
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                m_id = value

                Dim cmdSQL As New _
                    SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Fighters WHERE ID = @ID")

                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = m_id

                With MyRstP(cmdSQL).Rows(0)
                    Fighter = .Item("Fighter")
                    Engine = .Item("Engine")
                    Thrust = .Item("Thrust")
                    Description = .Item("Description")
                    ImagePath = Replace(.Item("ImagePath"), "~/", "../")

                End With
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
End Class
```

The effect and result of above is this:

[image]

Note in the above the return of the server side class. Note how I did not have to convert to  JSON, or even serialize that class I returned to the client side.

And also note, even if you just return a string, or as this example shows, a class: you use rData.d  the ".d" part is the return value.

So, I suppose I could have used in that code rData.d.Fighter for example.

And if you want to avoid the relative path names for say script references, then we could change this:

```
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <link  href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

to:

```
    <title></title>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js.js") %>
```

So, in summary:

You can't use "~/" in client-side JS code.

You HAVE to change the settings in routeConfig.vb

You HAVE to use the ".d"

You do NOT have to serialize the class or content - that is automatically done for you.